# Chef recipe fails using knife bootstrap but is successful using chef-client in windows target node

Tags: powershell, active-directory, chef-infra, powershell-remoting, chef-windows

I am using Chef-server-11.04 and the chef-client 11.12.4-1 for windows server 2012 r2.I am trying to execute Active directory powershell cmds on the windows client. The recipe execution fails when I use

*knife bootstrap windows winrm 10.XX.XXX.XX -x username -P xxxxxxx -r Adpowershell*

or

*knife winrm "name:example.co.in" "chef-client -r Adpowershell " -x username -P xxxxxxx

The error is ***Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running***.

The knife command is successful for other powershell cmds other than Active directory powerwshell cmds

But the recipe executed successfully when I try it using chef-client locally on node.

I have refered various links regarding this [unable to contact server](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/01/25/hey-scripting-guy-january-25-2010.aspx). But could'nt find any solution for Windows 2012 r2 . 
Can anyone tell me a solution for this problem

Comment: I can't give a final answer but I suspect this is due to credential replay (aka CredSSP in windows documentation). [some documentation about it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309365(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

On your server run:

```
winrm quickconfig -q
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="300"}'
winrm set winrm/config '@{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5985" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5985 action=allow
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5986" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5986 action=allow
```